# MySQL Query to find value of combined rows

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with these columns:

```
city
bookingdatetime (datetime)
promo
price
```

I want to query the table so I can see how much in dollars were spent using each specific promo code in only a specific city

So I want the output to look like this:

```
Month/Year      Promo     Amount Sent
01/20           xxx1      $45
01/20           xxx2      $10
02/20           xxx1      $30
```

Right now I am using this query to count the number of promo codes used in each month:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(promo, ' - ', DATE_FORMAT(bookingdatetime, '%m/%y')) AS promo,
  COUNT(*) AS count
FROM reservations
WHERE city = 'la'
  AND COALESCE(promo, '') <> ''
GROUP BY
  DATE_FORMAT(bookingdatetime, '%m/%y'),
  promo
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
ORDER BY
  DATE_FORMAT(bookingdatetime, '%y'),
  DATE_FORMAT(bookingdatetime, '%m')
```

So essentially I need to add the combined price column instead of just counting the number of rows.

Comment: Please share sample input data, and explain **exactly** what is not working with the given code and what you've tried to make it working

Comment: *I need to add the price column instead of just counting the number of rows.* Multiply calculated count of promos by the price per one promo...

Comment: I have no idea what isn't clear here...

Answer (score 0):

if you get an error for `sum(Amount Sent)`it is most probably because MySQL treats it as a string.

Try to get rid of the dollar sign and then sum it as usual:

```
sum(right(length(Amount Sent),length(Amount Sent)-1))
```